# javascript choose one date and next automatic set with 3 months diffrence

Tags: javascript, date

Please send me some suggestions and any link related to my query. I'm newbie in javascript or don't know where start.

```
//javascript codes
```

Comment: I have no idea of what you are asking for... but use momentjs for dates in js.. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: script like this... show automatic next date with 3 months difference from current date

Comment: normally you have 12 choices for month, but excluding the month of the current date it remains 11 choices. Randomly pick any 3 of 11 choices. The current date of the next cycle is the last one of the 3 picked. That loops again and again.

Comment: @king yes i do same way... and find the solution..thx all.. Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use momentjs when you are working with dates in javascript.. Its lightweight.
http://momentjs.com/

So to get the date 3 month ahead from current date its pretty easy with moment.

```
moment().add(3, "months")
```

Comment: Yes!!.. Thanks.. I do same way.. I got Solution.

Answer (score 0):

`var now  = new Date();` // Now Today.

`now.setMonth(now.getMonth() +3);` // Date added by 3 months.